# Route times out so memoize does not work

Tags: python, flask, python-rq, flask-cache

I have the current route

```
@app.route('/as/<keyword>', methods=['GET'])
@cache.memoize(timeout = 30 * 24 * 60 * 60)
def auto_suggest(keyword):
    job = q.enqueue(find_keyword, keyword, timeout = 60 * 60)
    while not job.result:
        time.sleep(1)
    return jsonify(word=job.result)
```

When I run this on local it works fine since it does not time out.  After the function is run once the result is saved into cache and on subsequent reloads it loads instantly. but once I put it on the server when I run the route it times out.

even though the task completes after the time out, when I reload the function it reruns the task instead of calling it from cache.

Is there another way I should be doing this?

Comment: What do you use to serve requests on server? Seems like requests are killed before job is completed.

Comment: If you use uwsgi it could be `harakiri` parameter in config.

Comment: @EugeneSoldatov nginx, standard route.  The function can take a while to run 15-30 minutes is not unheard of.  Not sure if I want to set headers to expire that long in nginx

Comment: I am running the task with python-rq, as can be seen by the ```q.enqueue``` in the background.  The result is what I'm trying to resolve

Comment: forgot to say I have it running on gunicorn

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and solved this by putting the long function in a redis key and calling the key from the route.

```
@app.route('/as/<keyword>', methods=['GET'])
def auto_suggest(keyword):
    if not redis.get(keyword):
        q.enqueue(find_keyword, keyword, timeout = 60 * 60)
        return jsonify(word=False)
    return jsonify(word=redis.get(keyword))
```